# What does this structure in Javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

Im learning javascript and I just dont understand what this javascript syntax actually means...

```
Comment = function () {

}
```

I know that in this context we use it to define an object but what is the stucture called where can I read about it?

Comment: I don't exactly see what you're asking here. This seems like a pretty straightforward variable assignment. `Comment` is the variable. Its value is a function. Note that the variable's value is not *the return value of* a function, but the actual function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a function named `Comment`, this is equivalent to:

```
function Comment() {

}
```

Because there is now `var` keyword like here:

```
var Comment = function() {}
```

the `Comment` variable will be added to global object called `window`, so it is equivalent to:

```
window.Comment = function() {

}
```

Also, by convention, capitalized function names are used for so called constructors:

```
var comment = new Comment();
```

Comment: Actually, it is not exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, they're not the same.  Your first example is a function declaration, the second and third are function expressions.  The most significant difference is that the former is hoisted.

Comment: I was surprised that in both cases, `Comment` is a variable. So, you can write `Comment='a string';` and it turns into a string. Many programming languages won't allow that.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is a function expression.

It creates an anonymous function and assigns it to the (global) variable `Comment`.

It is similar to `function Comment() {}` except one difference: It does not have a name so debuggers might just display `?` instead of a function name and more important, the function is defined when the line containing the definition is executed while function declarations are "executed" before the other code is executed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/nVrep/

Answer (score 1):

That is a [function operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/function) (as opposed to a [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) or [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function))

Comment: That's odd terminology by MDN: `function` strictly isn't an operator. The spec terminology is *function expression* and *function declaration*. *Function statement* is actually incorrect here, since that is another thing again (it's an extension in Mozilla that makes `if (foo) { function bar() {}; }`, which is not valid according to the ECMAScript spec, work).